# Enviar correo con CC PHPMailer

Tags: php, html5, phpmailer

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo mediante `PHPMailer` pero a este lo quiero enviar con `cc` a un listado que yo deseo poder seleccionar.
Tengo mi function en javascript donde selecciono a quien le llega este correo
mi listado de contacto.

```
function send_Mail() {

    var arr = [];
    $.each($("input[name='mail_cc']:checked"), function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(arr);

    var data_to_ajax = {
        "for": $("input[name=mail_for]").val(),
        "cc": arr
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'JSON/Mail.php',
        data: data_to_ajax,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            $('#modalMail').modal('hide');

        }
    });
}
```

Mi PHP file.

```
<?php

include_once('../../../CONEXION/conexion.php');
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'Email/Exception.php';
require 'Email/PHPMailer.php';
require 'Email/SMTP.php';


$for            = trim($_POST['for']);
$cc             = trim($_POST['cc']);
$fecha          = date('Y-m-d');
$fecha          = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha));

$message         = file_get_contents('Email/mail.html');
$message         = str_replace('%nro_contenedor%', $nro_contenedor, $message);
$message         = str_replace('%fecha%', $fecha, $message);
$mail            = new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions
// try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = '99.99.99.99'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'noreply@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = '******'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port       = 25; // TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('noreply@gmail.com', 'noreplay');
$mail->addAddress($for); // Add a recipient

foreach ($cc as $email) {
    $mail->AddCC($email, ''); //AQUI AGREGAR CON CC A LOS CONTACTOS.
}
//Content
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Control Calidad';
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = 'Control de Calidad ' . $fecha;


if ($mail->send()) {
    echo json_encode($nro_contenedor,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Puedo recibir el correo solo al `$mail->addAddress($for);` , pero no enviá con `cc` a los contactos ya seleccionados en las herramientas de desarrollador del browser puedo ver el POST con el array de `cc`

[Foto de mi CC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXhIN.jpg)

Comment: ¿Realmente `$cc` es un array con direcciones email válidas? ¿Podrías mostrar el resultado de un `var_dump($cc);`

Comment: @A.Cedano listo.

Comment: Quisiera ver un `var_dump($cc);` tal cual, nada más. Y no en fotos, lo puedes poner como texto en la pregunta. Puedes quitar las direcciones de email, poniendo algo como `"usuario@mail.com"` Lo importante es ver la estructura de los datos con los que estás trabajando. Me refiero al servidor, no al cliente. Es en el servidor donde debes verificar los datos. El `var_dump` informará de cómo están los datos, de qué  tipo son, qué contenido es array, o es string... etc.